# php PDO bindParam() width 2 dimensional array - foreach loop

Tags: php, pdo

can I ask somebody is this good solution
(value is passed to bindParam() in foreach as follows: 
**$var_value =  &$row['val'];**) 
or is it better solution for it  ?

I have array for example:

```
$array['city']['val']        = $city;  //city value passed to bindParam()
$array['city']['type']       = 'string'; //type passed to bindParam()
$array['city_id']['val']     = $city_id;   
$array['city_id']['type']    = 'int';     

$query = "update cities set city=:city where city_id=:city_id";
```

function to bind parameters:

```
function BindParameters($array,$query) {

        $st = $this->dbc->prepare($query);   

        if (is_array($array) && count($array)>0) {

            foreach ($array as $key=> $row) {

                if (isset($row['type'])) {
                    $var_type  = $row['type'];
                } else {
                    $var_type  = '';
                }

                $var_value =  &$row['val']; 

                if ($var_type=='int') {
                    $var_type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                } else if ($var_type=='string') {
                    $var_type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                } else if ($var_type=='null') {
                    $var_type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                } else {
                    $var_type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
                }
                $st->bindParam(':'.$key,$var_value,$var_type);
            }
        }
         $st->execute();
         return $st;
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always put parameters as array in `execute()`.

Comment: I preferred bindParam(), in case I will need to put data_type parameter

Comment: In that case, a loop is the only way.

Comment: I stayed width loop and bindParam(), thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, this solution is not good. It's inconvenient and error-prone.
Yes, there is a much better solution for running regular queries:

Just have your data in array like this

```
$array['city']    = $city;
$array['city_id'] = $city_id;
```

and then send it directly to `execute()`:

```
$query = "update cities set city=:city where city_id=:city_id";
$pdo->prepare($query)->execute($array);
```

which is *all* the code you need to run this query, no clumsy `BindParameters` function ever needed.

As long as you keep `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` as `false`, this approach won't make any trouble for you.

For the regular SQL query you never need neither `bindParam()` [nor it's third parameter](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindparam-parameters).

So, make this function as this

```
function run($query, $array = NULL) {

    $st = $this->dbc->prepare($query);   
    $st->execute($array);
    return $st;
}
```

Comment: regarding bindParam(), when it is better or I need to use it width data_type parameter ? because Iam passing values to execute() in this case